# flex: how to embed fonts for Spark FormItem?

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, flex4.5, flex4.6

Here is my CSS (flex4.6)

```
/* CSS file */
@namespace mx "library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx";
@namespace s "library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark";


@font-face {
    src:url("assets/MyriadWebPro.ttf");
    fontFamily: myCFFFont;
    embedAsCFF: true;
}

@font-face {
    src:url("assets/MyriadWebPro.ttf");
    fontFamily: myFontNoCFF;
    embedAsCFF: false;
}
mx|Application{
    fontFamily: myFontNoCFF;
}
mx|Button {
    fontFamily: myFontNoCFF;
}
mx|Label{
    fontFamily: myFontNoCFF;    
}

s|Application {
    fontFamily: myCFFFont;
}
s|FormItem {
    fontFamily: myCFFFont;
    fontStyle:normal;
    fontWeight:normal;
}

global {
    fontFamily: myCFFFont;
}
```

This is ok for labels, buttons etc... except for formitems:

```
<s:FormItem  width="346" label="{lang.msg_enter_nickname}">
```

These formItem render with not embed fonts.

What do I am doing wrong ?

Regards

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this problem, it's a bug in SDK (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLEX-26380). I tried to find workaround but didn't. Use mx:FormItem instead spark.